# How to modify YAML object with given key in object array?

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following file contents:

```yaml
animals:
  - rabbit:
      type: R
  - dog:
      type: D
  - cat:
      type: C
```

What I would want to do with `yq` is to find all keys that have an "a" in them ("cat" and "rabbit") and modify the file in place to add a "has_a: true" property, so end up with:

```yaml
animals:
  - rabbit:
      has_a: true
      type: R
  - dog:
      type: D
  - cat:
      has_a: true
      type: C
```

Ideally, I'd add the property at the first position, but don't modify any existing keys.

Could someone please give me a pointer how to do this with `yq`? I tried a whole bunch of things, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Does "don't modify any existing keys" include the case that also `.has_a` could alredy be present?

Comment: That could be another cherry on top, yes. But the current solution is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with [both implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq:

```bash
.animals[] |= with_entries(select(.key | contains("a")).value.has_a = true)
```

```yaml
animals:
  - rabbit:
      type: R
      has_a: true
  - dog:
      type: D
  - cat:
      type: C
      has_a: true
```

Use the `-i` option to modify the file in-place. For kislyuk/yq, also add the `-y` option to produce YAML.

---

> Ideally, I'd add the property at the first position

Properties only have an order in their representation. Logically, they are identical to any other order, and other tools along your processing chain could just revert any effort of ordering them. That said, you could make yq (both implementations in their currrent versions - this might change in the future) to output the new key first by adding the old value to it (in this order):

```bash
.animals[] |= with_entries(select(.key | contains("a")).value |= {"has_a": true} + .)
```

```yaml
animals:
  - rabbit:
      has_a: true
      type: R
  - dog:
      type: D
  - cat:
      has_a: true
      type: C
```

---

Tested with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) 3.2.3, and [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) 4.34.2